# how to To extract a two-by-two table for a specific event

Tags: javascript-objects

```
 function tableFor(event, journal) {
 let table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
 for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
     let entry = journal[i], index = 0;
     if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
     if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
     table[index] += 1;
}
return table;
}
 console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

[JOURNAL file](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/journal.js)

I'm reading eloquent javascript third edition and I find it difficult to understand this code, especially the if conditions. My question is why in the `entry.events.includes(event)`, index should increment by 1 and in `entry.squirrel` should increment by 2?
I addition, if both ifs in the for loop are true, `table[index] += 1` will be incremented or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 states to consider:

1. If the event in the journal does not contain pizza and is not a squirrel then increment table at index 0
2. If the event in the journal contains 'pizza' but not squirrel table is incremented at index 1
3. If the event does not contain 'pizza' but squirrel is true then the table will be incremented at index 2
4. If **BOTH** the event contains "pizza" and squirrel is true then the table will be incremented at index 3

This will loop over the JSON object in the JOURNAL file. For each "event" one of these 4 states will be chosen and the table variable will be affected in the above manner.